# pip install cryptography fails with a proxy error

Tags: python-2.7

Python version = 2.7.13

OS version = Windows 7

I am behind a corporate proxy, trying to install paramiko and crypotagrphy. I searched for a solution but none worked. I tried the following so far to no use.

1. **Tried setting the proxy variable on windows.
2. Tried installing urllib3.
3. Also tried creating a pip folder with a pip.ini file and pasted my proxy address there.

I get the following error when using

pip install --proxy=http:// crytography

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection
failed: 405 Method Not Allowed',))': /simple/cryptography/
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Was able to install pycrypto but the pip install paramiko still fails.

Comment: >>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 33, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends